# How to refresh a page after 30 seconds for 5 times?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to refresh a page for `5` times each after `30` seconds.
I can't use the `document.location.reload()` js function since the whole page reloads when the js is executed again.
Any ideas?

Comment: store reload count in localstorage or cookie and reload until count is 5.

Answer (score 5):

Use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

```js
let refreshNum = sessionStorage.getItem('refreshNum') || 0;

if(refreshNum<5) {
  console.log('before 5 refresh');
  refreshNum++;
  sessionStorage.setItem('refreshNum', refreshNum);
  // refresh your page here
  setTimeout(()=> document.location.reload(), 30000)
} else {
  console.log('after 5 refresh');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use to reload the page with a get parameter in url:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href + "?reloadCount=0";
```

then after 30 second from the page load:

```
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
var reloadCount = urlParams.get('reloadCount');
```

next if reloadCount >= 5 stop reloading the page otherwise add 1 to reload count and reload the page with updated paremeter

```
window.location.href = window.location.href + "?reloadCount=1";
```

Comment: 2 problems with using a query param here..   1. this will invalidate your cache, IOW: the page will be fetched 5 times when 1 would have done.  2. Depends on the back-end knowing about query params.  But your idea does have merit, use a hash fragment instead of a query param.

Comment: yes, the hash is a good variation, you're right! `window.location.hash.replace('#','','g');` and  in the reload url append only the count `window.location.href + "?#0"; `

Answer (score 0):

With php you can use session to store the time + 5*30 seconds ahead.
Then use html meta refresh to reload the page

```
session_start(); // not in head. Must be at the top of the document



if(!isset($_session['time'])){
    $_session['time'] = time() +150;
}else{
    if(time() < $_session['time']) echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='30'>";
}
```

And place that in the head of the html.

Because this is serverside it also works when a client have JavaScript off.